# How to use \FIG to cite a figure in text and change the name of the citation

Tags: floats, citing

Currently my code looks like

```
\FIG{fig.my_label} %to cite a picture in the text
```

The text shows like [image: Figure 1]

But I want to change the citation name like this
[image: Figure 1A]

And in my article, the figure is a single picture and not a sub-picture, so I want to change the name to specifically refer to the small picture A. Any advice?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm sorry for this, I'm using LaTeX for thesis typesetting for the first time, and I'm not yet proficient in it, I re-edited my question, looking forward to your answer！

Comment: How you define `\FIG` command?  If I correctly understood your problem, you like extent its use `\FIG{fig.my_label{A}`.

Comment: `\FIG` is not a standard command and you have not shown how you have defined it, so no one can answer this